# Format a Textview which lists all SQL table entries in Android Studio

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I have a piece of code which lists the content of my table, which contains a list of persons with various results...

I was able to get the values displayed in a Textview, like this :

1 Bob 0 0 0 0
2 Renee 0 0 0 0
3 Jason 0 0 0 0
4 Sandy 0 0 0 0

Is it possible to "style" it in order to have column content aligned?
How may I set up the column "width"?!

Here is the code retrieving the data ...

```
try
    {
        db=openOrCreateDatabase("mydatabase",SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY,null);
        Cursor c= db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM mytable",null);

        TextView v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.v);
        c.moveToFirst();

        String temp="";
        while(! c.isAfterLast()) {
            String s1=c.getString(0);
            String s2=c.getString(1);
            String s3=c.getString(2);
            String s4=c.getString(3);
            String s5=c.getString(4);
            String s6=c.getString(5);
            temp=temp+"\n"+s1+"\t"+s2;
            c.moveToNext();
        }
        v.setText(temp);

    }
    catch(SQLiteException e)
    {

    }

}
```

... and puts it in the following Textview :

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/v"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   />
```

Well, thank you very much in advance!

Comment: There is really no good way to do this inside a single TextView. You are probably better off using some kind of TableLayout, or implementing a ListView with rows that are better structured for displaying the data. You also should use a StringBuilder instead of using string concatenation in your for loop, and close the cursor when you're finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do two things. Using attributes like `android:padding` and `android:margin` on your TextView to position the text where you wish on the page. You can then also separate the "columns" in text using tab characters between each value on a line.

```
String s1 = c.getString(0);
s1 = s1.replaceAll("\\s","\t");
```

This way despite their length they will all share starting locations on a line (unless of course one string exceeds the length of a tab character, then it may be shifted over.)

Comment: But I do not understand how it is that, in a single TextView, there are several "rows" of data displayed! Will there be a TextView for each entry, or a single Textview with several "rows"?

Comment: @bat.t You will be able to do either. You can create a TextView for each row, which may allow the ability to customize each independently, but if you want to display the data in a table-format using a TextView it is possible to put each string, followed by a newline character '\n' in the TextView, also doing what I've mentioned above. This should format it how you wish.